# PHP/MySQL Concurrency - Write dependent on Read - Critical Section

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, concurrency, critical-section

I have a website running PHP+MySQL. It is a multiuser system and most of the MySQL tables are MyISAM-based.

The following situation got me puzzled for the last few hours:
I have two (concurrent) users A,B. Both of them will do this:

1. Perform a Read Operation on Table 1
2. Perform a Write Operation on another Table 2 (only if the previous Read operation will return a distinct result, e.g. STATUS="OK")

B is a little delayed towards A.

So it will occur like this:

- User A performs a read on Table 1 and sees STATUS="OK".
- (User A Schedules Write on Table 2)
- User B performs a read on Table 1 and still sees STATUS="OK".
- User A performs Write on Table 2 (resulting in STATUS="NOT OK" anymore)
- User B performs Write on Table 2 (assuming STATUS="OK")

I think I could prevent this if Reading Table 1 and Writing to Table 2 were defined as a critical section and would be executed atomically. I know this works perfectly fine in Java with threads etc., however in PHP there is no thread communication, as far as I know.

So the solution to my problem must be database-related, right?
Any ideas?

Thanks a  lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Right Way:** Use InnoDB and [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html).

**The Wrong-But-Works Way:** Use the [GET_LOCK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) MySQL function to obtain an exclusive named lock before performing the database operations. When you're don, release the lock with [RELEASE_LOCK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-lock). Since only one client can own a particular lock, this will ensure that there's never more than one instance of the script in the "critical section" at the same time.

Pseudo-code:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('mylock', 10);
If the query returned "1":
    //Read from Table 1
    //Update Table 2
    SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('mylock');
Else:
    //Another instance has been holding the lock for > 10 seconds...
```

Comment: Thx, I read something similar. The only thing I am not sure about is how "blocking" will be handled in this case. I don't want other concurrent operations to be blocked and thrown away, instead I'd like MySQL to put them into a queue. Are you familiar with how this works?

Comment: @InnoDB: I was also thinking about switching to that engine. However can this really solve my problem of executing several DB queries in a block / critical section ? I thought InnoDB could "just" solve any other concurrency issues, but mine :D

Comment: With InnoDB, you can wrap your DB operations in a transaction. This will in effect make them an atomic block. As for locks, if you try to get a lock while another client is already holding it, your script will pause for up to $timeout seconds (10 seconds in my example). If the lock gets released during this time, it will take the lock and proceed as normal. If the timeout expires, well, it's up to you to decide what happens then. You could just retry.